# Is it important to use $timeout in angularJS while using Async and Await ing Asp.net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asynchronous

I just want to know if it is required to use `$timeout` in `AngularJS` as a synchronous way while I'm using `Async` and `Await` in my Serverside which is the `Asp.Net Web Api`.

Please explain me and let me understand if I'm going to use `$timeout`, `Async` and `Await` together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Async\Await` are `server side` operators that help you do things **async** in your server.

`$timeout` is a `angularjs` provider that wraps `setTimeout` and uses the `$apply` function to sync things in the **angular world**(`$apply` calls `digest`).

If you are looking for a way to be `async` on the **client** side you should read about `promises` and `deferred` objects - This is the way to work `async` on the **client**(it doesn't matter if I'm async on server or not).

Comment: is it enough to use async in serverside only?

Comment: @DatzMe  - No. An http request is something that you don't want to wait for on the client end. You don't want to block your code until the response comes back and therefore you work with deferred objects and promises to accomplish before and after actions (callbacks). Your server can handle the request in a sync or async way. The client shouldn't care about it.